# Are there any alternatives in HTML for the entities &cap; and &cup;?

Tags: html, html-entities, symbols

I am using the Symbol font within an Illustrator graphic. Now, I would like to use the same symbols directly in HTML. I found equivalents to phi (φ), rho (ρ), and even the check box like symbol: ✓. However, I am missing the open and close arcs from the Symbol font. They are equivalent to ∩ and ∪, but they seem wider. So...is there a better alternative to map the Symbol font entities to HTML entities?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.snible.org/greek/symb2uni.html

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, it does not recognize the symbol correctly. Also, I found this sites: http://www.alanwood.net/demos/symbol.html and http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/index.php . They do not provide the symbol I am searching for.

Comment: I think that's simply the way those characters look like in the Symbol font - just every character looks differently in different fonts. If you are using the symbols for (set) union and intersection, then `&cap;` and `&cup;` are the correct characters. If you are using them for something else (such as semicircles) you should say so, because that would make it easier to find the correct symbols.

Comment: If you are using them for semicircles, then you should stop and use images instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are searches for some alternatives for

- [cap](http://ndpsoftware.com/&what/#q=intersection)
- [cup](http://ndpsoftware.com/&what/#q=cup) and [union](http://ndpsoftware.com/&what/#q=union)

It looks like the n-ary ones might be good, but I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for.

Note that you can try different web fonts by mousing over over the top right corner where it says "Font?"

I wrote this tool to help discover these, so I hope it helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
&#8745; 
&#8746;
```

Comment: These are the same as *&cap;* and *&cup;*

Answer (score 0):

You can find it easy, just use search

http://www.unicodeblocks.com/search/cup%20union%20intersection

or choose the block:

http://www.unicodeblocks.com/block/Mathematical_Operators

Html code can be found there as well.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! To make your answer better, you should include the important aspects of a link, as the link may break at some point in time or be removed.